# How to pass complex type object from one domain to sub domain

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xmlhttprequest, dns, subdomain

I need to pass the reservation type object from one main domain to sub domain where is a page which have installed ssl . so its necessary to send all values there and consume there/

I tired to create a web service with following method

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<Reservation> getReservation()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["reservation"] != null)
        {
            return (List<Reservation>)HttpContext.Current.Session["reservation"];
        }
        else
        {
            List<Reservation> objres = new List<Reservation>();
            return objres;
        }


    }
```

so i can consume that web service in sub domain page

following code is written on ssl enabled page

```
  string FullUrl = "http://localhost/goldlinetravel/webservice.asmx/getReservation";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FullUrl.ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
            request.Accept = "application / xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            DataSet dsReservation = new DataSet();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                response.GetResponseStream();

                dsReservation.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
```

its throwing error 500 server error.

there is another method in web service

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

when i consume this web service with following code there is no error

```
string FullUrl = "http://localhost/goldlinetravel/webservice.asmx/HelloWorld";
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(FullUrl.ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Accept = "application / xml";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = 0;
            DataSet dsReservation = new DataSet();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                response.GetResponseStream();

                dsReservation.ReadXml(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
```

I am not getting what is wrong in my getReservation method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled session in your web service if you intend to use it:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<Reservation> getReservation()
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously now that you have enabled session, this doesn't mean that `HttpContext.Current.Session["reservation"]` will give you anything other than `null`. You must have first stored something into the session. And this should be done in the same web service, not from the outside. You cannot share sessions between ASP.NET applications.

Comment: you are right no error but still the session null. so how can i use hotel page reservation object in web service .so reservation page which is on another domain can consume that web service and get the object

Comment: question is still unanswered and if i am using wromg approach please give me direction to complete this task

Comment: ASP.NET sessions are tracked by cookies. Who is writing the value to the session? Is it the ASP.NET application or another web method? You need to send the session cookie along with the request. But I am not going into details about this because it is wrong to use sessions in a web service. You should pass the information that the service needs, or have the service fetch the information from some backend where it was previously written, not the session.